# How to change part of a URL and use items from a list to replace the addresses in Python?

Tags: python, json

I'd like to change part of an URL and store them in a list of URLs and then I'll parse the JSON files. I'm not familiar with advanced loops and whiles yet. I'm still learning and studying every day. =)

My script so far:

import json

#### I have a list of channels like this:

```
channels = ['channel_1', 'channel_2', 'channel_3']
```

#### Collect date:

```
start_date = input('Insert the start date here: ')
final_date = input('Insert the final date here: ')
```

#### The name of the website objects (only one each collect)

```
website_object = input('type the website_object here: ')

url = 'www.domain.com/{channel}/{website_object}/other/things/of/the/huge/url/startDate={start_date}/finalDate={final_date}'.format(channel, website_object, start_date, final_date)
```

#### I'd like to create a list of URLs to iterate and parse the JSON files of each one of the channels like this:

```
url_list = ['www.domain.com/channel_1/object_1', 
            'www.domain.com/channel_2/object_1', 
            'www.domain.com/channel_3/object_1']
```

#### Then, I'll parse the JSON files here using this url_list, something like this:

```
for address in url_list:
    data_json = json.loads(address.read())
```

Each time I run the script, I intend to collect data from only one website_object which has many channels. I'm using this example with only 3 channels, but there are cases where it has 12 or more.

What is the best way to reach this goal in a loop to create a list of changed URLs according to each channel name?

Comment: Is your url fixed to this `'www.domain.com/{channel}/{website_object}'`? Why not just loop over the channels and substitute each value to the `channel` part?

Comment: My URL has many other words. I'll edit the question to make it more clear. Thank you  
Niel Godfrey Ponciano =D

Comment: I added an answer which will produce the urls per channel. I think it covers what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you already have the url to change, you can easily use [map()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) to apply it to your list of channels:

```
channels = ['channel_1', 'channel_2', 'channel_3']
url_list = list(map(lambda channel: f'www.domain.com/{channel}/object_1', channels))
print(url_list)
```

**Output**

```
[
    'www.domain.com/channel_1/object_1',
    'www.domain.com/channel_2/object_1',
    'www.domain.com/channel_3/object_1'
]
```

Then, if you also have different objects that you want to map per channel, you can use [itertools.product()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
from itertools import product

objects = ['object_1', 'object_2']
url_list = list(
    map(
        lambda channel_obj: f'www.domain.com/{channel_obj[0]}/{channel_obj[1]}',
        product(channels, objects),
    )
)
print(url_list)
```

**Output**

```
[
    'www.domain.com/channel_1/object_1',
    'www.domain.com/channel_1/object_2',
    'www.domain.com/channel_2/object_1',
    'www.domain.com/channel_2/object_2',
    'www.domain.com/channel_3/object_1',
    'www.domain.com/channel_3/object_2'
]
```